# Web Api 2 Individual Accounts: integrate with existing database

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

In Visual Studio 2013 i have a web application solution with 2 project:

> 1)StrokeInModel(that is entity framework database first)
>
> 2)MyProject (Web Api 2 project with reference to MyEntity project to access to the database)

For example in a controller of MyProject i have:

```
public class ListController : ApiController
{
     private StrokeInEntities db = new StrokeInEntities();
     ...
}
```

And in the "StrokeInModel.Context.cs" i have the following code:

```
public partial class StrokeInEntities : DbContext
{
    public StrokeInEntities()
        : base("name=StrokeInEntities")
    {
    }
    ...
}
```

How can i use the Individual Accounts in Web API to access the existing database? I'd like that the user registration ecc.. are in the existing database and not in the LocalDB. Where i must put the connection string?

Comment: you mean in which project you should have the Ef related configuration. if thats the case then it should be in your webapi project.

Answer (score 1):

from your example

```
public StrokeInEntities()
        : base("name=StrokeInEntities")
    {
    }
```

the string you pass to the base constructor could be either a database name or a connection string name.

Therefore i could have done

```
public StrokeInEntities()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }
```

and in the web.config of the wep api project defined a connection string as

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection"
         connectionString="Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=StrokeInEntities;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```